# Operating Point Parameters for Stacked Transistor

Tags: mosfet, analog

I've just recently started working with FinFETs for the first time. One of the Pcells included in the PDK is a stackSeries device. This allows you to choose one of the transistors in the PDK and then choose the number to place in series, the minimum being 2 devices. This appears to be done as the maximum length of any single device is quite limited so by stacking the devices you can achieve what is essentially a single transistor with your desired length.

The following diagram shows a single device being expanded into its stacked equivalent. I only show 3 transistors in the stack but this could be whatever really. Also typically the length for FinFETs is somewhat discretised, in that only certain lengths are allowed, but this shouldn't matter for this question.

[image: Converting single device into stacked devices]

So now comes my question, given a stacked device, such as the one in the image above, how might we go about finding the operating point parameters for the top level transistor? (Apologies if the wording is confusing here...!) For example, I would like to see if my transistor is in saturation or not. However the simulator will only report the threshold voltage and Vdsat for each individual transistor in the stack, not the overall device.

**Is there a straightforward way to use the operating point parameters of the individual transistors in the stack to inform you of the operating point parameters of the overall equivalent transistor?**

Some thoughts about this:

- A quick method that would work for checking saturation could be to just check V_GS > Vth and V_GD < Vth, however which value of Vth would you use? Each individual transistor in the stack has a slightly different threshold voltage. This is also really just a hand calculation and it would be nicer to use a more accurate metric, such as Vdsat for the transistor.
- There appears to be a built in method for finding operating point parameters for a stacked transistor within Cadence Virtuoso however the values it's returning me seem to be rubbish. I've posted on the Cadence forums to follow up on that.

I hope that's clear, let me know if you'd like anymore detail.

Comment: Since the transistors is in parallel their capacitance is added. What does that mean?

Comment: The transistors are in series here. Are you referring to a specific node?

Comment: Each MOSFET has a MOS capacitor inside it made of the gate dialetric and the substrate. Since the charging of this capacitor really controls the flow of current. Since all the gates have the same potential and all the substrates have the same potential(0 no current flows) the Mos capacitors are in parallel.

Comment: @HelenaWells Once the channel forms, the capacitance will be to the channel and not to the substrate. The channel voltage is not the same as the substrate voltage so the gate capacitances are **not** strictly in parallel. Furthermore, the substrate connections are not even shown in the schematic so assuming that they are all connected could be incorrect.

Comment: Elliot Anderson in modern MOSFETs the substrate has the same potential with the source.

Comment: The bulk and the source are not necessarily connected. In fact, for NMOS we often don't connect the bulk and source as NMOS devices are not isolated in their own wells like PMOS. In the case where we do really want to short the bulk and source in the NMOS you pay a large area penalty as you now have to create a separate well for the NMOS, called a hot well. Modern stacked FinFETs apparently exhibit a much smaller body effect so connecting the bulk and source for each individual device isn't that advantageous.

Comment: @HelenaWells No, it is not necessarily true that the substrate has the same voltage as the source, not in VLSI design. The substrate is likely connected to the most negative voltage in the circuit, whereas the source voltage can change in stacked transistors. In SOI processes the substrate may be completely floating.

Comment: What about a **straightforward** simulation of your circuit with a FinFET BSIM-CMG model? Is it absolutely necessary to invent an entity "overall equivalent transistor"? In a sense, use of FinFET devices facilitate analysis: suppressed short channel effects, less channel length modulation. As a result, less or no "hand calculation".

Comment: I am simulating with the BSIMCMG model. However, I noted in my question that the operating points are only reported for each of the individual devices. Part of my motivation here is the Poor Man's Cascode, where the equivalent device is considered in saturation but when you look at the two individual devices, one is in saturation and one is in triode. So if I was just looking at the individual devices it could be quite misleading.

Comment: Do you mean "poor man's cascode" like in slide 77/83, http://ee.sut.ac.ir/People/Courses/135/Chapter%203.pptx ? There is also a criterion you are looking for: V_GS1 > V_TH1 and V_DS2> = V_GS2 − V_GS1 < V_GS2 −V_TH2. But, for starter, you'd better analyze your circuitry as is, without "stacked equivalent" .SUBCKT's. The "overall equivalent transistor" entity may prove to be not so useful or outright superfluous.

Comment: My only problem with going down this route is that there may be many of these stacked devices, with each stack consisting of many individual devices, so gaining any insight into how the circuit is performing will be extremely tedious. I just assumed there would be a more efficient way of approaching these FinFET stacks.